# when moving my rig, everything else moves how do I fix this?

Tags: mesh, rigging

When I move my rig everything moves with it.
https://youtu.be/UJAkWApYBUQ
check this video for clarity.
why is this happening and how do I fix this

Comment: you've enabled the Proportional Editing option, disable it